# Default highlight tableview cell not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I created a table view and each cell contains an image (covers the entire cell) and a title in the center. However, when I highlight one of the cells, nothing happens. It doesn't get darker which I thought was default. I tried using the code below to fix this, but it doesn't work.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = (tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MainPackCell)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
        cell.packImageView.highlightedImage = cell.packImageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            cell.packImageView.tintColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.3)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I selected style but there is no Grey option

Comment: You can use a Button with an image, instead of an ImageView to get that highlight effect.

Comment: So the button would have no functionality besides showing a highlight effect correct? The tableview cell will still be able to send you to the detail view? Or is the button actually sending you to the detail view? @Barsam

Comment: Sorry my bad change the cell Selection Instead of style

Comment: @MayankWadhwa I did that and it created a box that covered the entire image and then when I clicked on it and returned back to it it would stay selected. I'm just looking for a simple highlight effect that makes the cell a tad bit darker when you press on it and let go.

Answer (score 0):

Populate the TableVIew and refer to the Screenshot below:---

[image]

Use this and it is Done:-- Man
implement it after cellForRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I did that and it created a box that covered the entire image and then when I clicked on it and returned back to it it would stay selected. I'm just looking for a simple highlight effect that makes the cell a tad bit darker when you press on it and let go.

Comment: Definitely getting close! Is there a way to change it from gray to black? And possibly make the black have 50% opacity?

Comment: Try adding:   let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
                     cell?.backgroundColor = .black

Comment: Where do I add it? Inside the didSelectRowAt? It won't let me add it in cellForRowAt

Comment: you can add it in did select method but challenge for you will be to put any color on selected and change back to clear color on deselection

Comment: I've been trying and can't for the life of me get it to work :(

Comment: I added it to the didSelect method but it says Use of unresolved identifier 'cell'

Comment: let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) cell?.backgroundColor = .black  do this declare cell like above